# Apache virtual host how to add location with headers?

Tags: apache-2.4, docker, liferay

So I'm using liferay and an apache in docker and want to have the following URL localhost/tester when a user enters this I want headers to be added to their request. I tried to solve this with a simple virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    <Location /tester>
      RequestHeader append tester "true"
      Satisfy Any
      Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I try to navigate to localhost/tester I just get "Resource not found"

Comment: Do you have content at the /tester location?

Comment: No, i just wanted as a path through which i can add headers. So if a user  goes through localhost/tester/index then they arrive at index with certain headers

and if they go through localhost/index they arrive at index without those headers.

Comment: You might run liferay, but this question doesn't show any trace of it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Apache is telling you that it doesn't know what content to serve from `http://localhost/tester`. You need to give it a `DocumentRoot`, say

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

and then create a file `tester/index.html` within that. The file can be empty.